How to have IHttpContextAccessor if Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions si deprecated in a netstandard 2.0 project?
I can't find a solution that fit on my project. The project is a netstandard 2.0 project and all the solutions I found are referred to .net projects.
My project uses IHttpContextAccessor to get HttpContext.Connection.Id.
How I can solve it?
Thank you

That's because .NET Standard is only meant for libraries, not executable applications. What's the version of your web app? The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6 - the Core part was removed in .NET 5 for marketing reasons. There's no reason to target .NET Standard 2.0 unless you intend to target .NET Framework as well

I think being deprecated doesn't mean being removed.

Can you add <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" /> to your csproj?

@PanagiotisKanavos you are no reason, I have to keep legacy code behind

@shingo I know the difference between deprecated and removed, is it all you can suggest? difference between English terms?

@DavidG  actually it's the reason why I asked, this solution you proposed  not for .netstandard2.0. I need it works there

You haven't explained what the actual runtime is. There's no supported ASP.NET Core version that runs on .NET Framework so there's no reason to target .NET Standard 2.0. In all supported .NET Core versions (6,8), IHttpContextAccessor is provided by the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref package, which is added automatically when the csproj file uses Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web".

I need it works there  why? Are you sure? The last ASP.NET Core version that supported .NET Framework was 2.2, in 2018, which is why there's no version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions since.  Are you really targeting ASP.NET Core 2.2 ?

The difference means the package still exist, you can keep using it.

@PanagiotisKanavos all the webApi goal I made it's to cover legacy codebase until the company will decide to drop out or update the .net framework (good luck!). So, I built a .netstandard 2.0 project to bridge .net to .net framework. In this scenario I'm using jwt covering all the old style session, but all this thing is based to have the connection Id. So all I did it become deprecated thanks a nuget package I used in .netstandard 2.0. I'm risking on further .net version to not have this connection Id I really need.

@shingo As the .NET ecosystem evolves, deprecated packages may not be compatible with newer versions of the runtime, frameworks, or other libraries. This can lead to runtime errors, compilation issues, or unexpected behavior. Are you really sure to work in the real world of developers?

@lunatic84 we know about ASP.NET Core and its history, we've been through it. You seem to be making assumptions and expecting to hear what you want. Sorry. You're already tied to ASP.NET Core. IHttpContextAccessor doesn't exist in ASP.NET, whether you target .NET Standard or not. To get your library to work you'd have to provide your own implementation that returns the ambient HttpContext

@lunatic84 so the real answers, like them or not, are either 1) keep using the unmaintained, not just deprecated, package and assume the risk (which you already did for the last 6 years) or 2) ditch .NET Standard 2.0 for this library that wouldn't work outside ASP.NET Core anyway and upgrade.

@lunatic84 if the question is whether the package will be deleted - maybe. It's unmaintained for 5 years already. Shingo answered very well. Unsupported doesn't mean removed, and Microsoft rarely removes packages, unless there's a support cost. But that is unsupported, so there's no support at all. Read the linked deprecation GH Issue - no promises either way.

@PanagiotisKanavos ok, you convinced me. At least I'll try to move the code to another .net project. Thank you

I believe you are looking for

ActionExecutingContext

in the namespace

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters

Then you can use
public void Something(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
  //context.HttpContext....
}


even this package is deprecated
